# How can a weekday string return from NSDateComponents by passing an integer?

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

Assume I know the day by its integer value but I want to get a string value of the weekday in the locale of the user. Can `NSDateComponents` be used without a date object to somehow return the day (E.g. Monday) by passing an integer?

Currently I'm using dictionary with the days of the week but this obviously is far from ideal as far as user location is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Get the numeric day of week and then use NSDateFormatter's `weekdaySymbols` (or `shortWeekdaySymbols`) to fetch an NSArray of the names of the week days.

The NSDateFormatter needs to have a valid NSCalendar/NSLocale set but otherwise does not need to "know" what the current date/time is.

Answer (score 1):

Hot Licks' answer is great. Vote that one up.

To see the poor guy's solution who writes 10 lines when only one is needed, you could also get by with knowing 2006 had Sunday on the 1st of Jan.

```
let weekday = 1 // the day you want text for, 1 == sunday
var comps = NSDateComponents()
comps.year = 2006
comps.day = weekday
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
let d = calendar?.dateFromComponents(comps)
let f = NSDateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "eee" // short day style, "Sun", there are more available
let dayName = f.stringFromDate(d!)
```

I can't see any advantage to this approach  :)